# Executing Python/Ruby script in Android using eclipse

Tags: javascript, android, sl4a, ase

I want to execute Python/ Ruby/ Javascript scripts in an Android project. I need to develop using eclipse. I saw about SL4A. Could someone guide me how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the link http://jokar-johnk.blogspot.fi/2011/02/how-to-make-android-app-with-sl4a.html and was able to create Android application project.